# Understanding mapping spaces in higher category theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

I'm trying to understand the mapping space of two objects in an infinity category. Below is context and definitions, but please let me know if I have any misunderstandings.

The source of everything below is [Jacob Lurie's Higher Topos Theory, section 1.2.2](http://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Elurie/papers/highertopoi.pdf#page=44).

Let $S$ be an $\infty$-category. Let $x$ and $y$ be objects of $S$. The morphism space $\operatorname{Map}_{S}(x,y)$ is an object of the homotopy category which represents the space of maps from $x$ to $y$. It can be represented up to homotopy by the simplicial set of right morphisms $\operatorname{Hom}_{S}^{R}(x,y)$. This simplicial set is, in degree $n$, the set of all $(n+1)$-simplices in $S$ such that the $(n+1)$th vertex is $y$ and all the other vertices are $x$.

My own perspective currently is the $\infty$-category $s\mathbf{Alg}_{k}$, the simplicial $k$-algebras. I will write $R_{\bullet}$ and $S_{\bullet}$ to denote simplicial $k$-algebras. So in this case, $\operatorname{Map}_{s\mathbf{Alg}_{k}}(R_{\bullet},S_{\bullet})$ is represented by the homotopy type of a simplicial set that is in degree $n$, the collection of $(n+1)$-simplices with vertices $R_{\bullet},\ldots,R_{\bullet},S_{\bullet}$ with maps that make every triangle commute. For instance, in degree $1$, we have the set of all possible $2$-simplices, i.e., commutative triangles

\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{ccc}   
R_{\bullet} & \rightarrow & S_{\bullet}\\
& \searrow & \uparrow\\
& & R_{\bullet}
\end{array}  
\end{align*}
with any possible maps that make the triangle commute.

My questions:

> 1. Is my characterization of $\operatorname{Map}_{S}(x,y)$ and $\operatorname{Hom}_{S}^{R}(x,y)$ correct? I am doing a bit of decoding from Lurie, so I have written these objects in the way I understand them, not verbatim how Lurie defines them.
> 2. Suppose $f:S_{\bullet}\to T_{\bullet}$ is a map in $s\mathbf{Alg}_{k}$. How do I understand the induced map $\operatorname{Map}_{s\mathbf{Alg}_{k}}(R_{\bullet},S_{\bullet})\to\operatorname{Map}_{s\mathbf{Alg}_{k}}(R_{\bullet},T_{\bullet})$? Can I understand it as the map which, in degree $n$, takes an $(n+1)$-simplex of the form $R_{\bullet},\ldots,R_{\bullet},S_{\bullet}$ and produces an $(n+1)$-simplex $R_{\bullet},\ldots,R_{\bullet},T_{\bullet}$ where every map $R_{\bullet}\to R_{\bullet}$ remains untouched, while a map $R_{\bullet}\to S_{\bullet}$ gets sent to the map $R_{\bullet}\to S_{\bullet}\xrightarrow{f}T_{\bullet}$?

Comment: I'm pretty sure in Lurie's definition you'd want the maps $R_\bullet \to R_\bullet$ in your notation to be degenerate edges, i.e., identity maps.  Also, the diagrams only "commute up to homotopy", but that's circular, really.

Comment: @JHF I'm waffling back and forth on whether or not $R_{\bullet}\to R_{\bullet}$ should be identities or not. How are the degrees of the simplicial set of right morphisms different? It seems to me like there'd be a one-to-one correspondence between, e.g., commuting triangles in degree 2 and commuting tetrahedrons in degree 3. And the face and degeneracy maps would seem to do nothing. Does that make sense? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "commuting".  How many simplices in each degree depends on the simplicial set $S$ (and the objects, of course) so I don't see why there would be a correspondence unless $S$ is very special.  I also think the face maps can be very interesting: for example, the faces of a 2-simplex tells you which maps (= 1-simplices) are homotopic (the 2-simplex itself "is" the homotopy).

Comment: @JHF By commuting I mean that an $(n+1)$-simplex in $\hom_{S}^{R}(x,y)_{n}$ has vertices which are objects $x,y\in S$ and edges $x\to x$ or $x\to y$ as needed in $S$, built up in the shape of a geometric $(n+1)$-simplex with one vertex $y$ and the rest $x$, and such a diagram needs to commute, right? There must be something fundamental I am missing. If all the maps between $R_{\bullet}$s are the identity, then that means the maps $R_{\bullet}\to S_{\bullet}$ must all be the same map, in order for the diagram to commute. Hence why I think $R_{\bullet}\to R_{\bullet}$ needn't be the identity.

Comment: No, the diagrams don't have to commute; they just have to be $(n+1)$-simplices in $S$.   In fact, if you think of $S$ just as a simplicial set, it doesn't even make sense to say that a simplex "commutes".  Of course, when modelling $\infty$-categories as quasicategories, the presence of a simplex should be *interpreted* as a homotopy between its faces, i.e, the faces "homotopy commute", but this is an observation and not part of the definition.

Comment: I think the commutativity isn't the thrust of the question really. @Eric seems to be working with $S = sAlg_k$ explicitly, and applying Lurie's general statement about right hom. So the vertices of the simplicies are clear as $sAlg_k$ is the nerve of $Alg_k$, so these are $n$-fold compositions in sAlg_k. The question Eric is asking is, what are the maps of these simplicies?

Comment: I also think, reading the language that the maps in these simplicies are arbitrary, not identity.

Comment: @lemiller No, the restriction to $\Delta^{0,1,\ldots,n}$ is the *constant* simplex, which means the maps should be identity maps.  This agrees with the definition $\operatorname{Hom}^R_S(x,y) = S_{/y} \times_S \{x\}$ given later on.  See also [here](https://kerodon.net/tag/01KW).

Comment: @JHF, humm, okay, so this basically takes a single map $R_* \to S_*$ and gives essentially trivial homotopies of it? The Kerdon definition seems to suggest only one of the face maps is identity. Clearly a not all maps can be identity if the vertices aren't all the same, right?

Comment: @lemiller Let me be more explicit.  A $1$-simplex of $\operatorname{Hom}^R_S(x,y)$ is a special kind of $2$-simplex of $S$.  Vertices 0 and 1 of this $2$-simplex are $x$, and vertex 2 is $y$.  There are also three edges.  The edge opposite vertex 2 is the identity $x \to x$.  The other two edges are two maps $f_0, f_1: x \to y$, not necessarily the same.  The fact that this triangle can be "filled in" means that $f_0$ and $f_1$ should be regarded as homotopic.

Comment: @JHF, thanks, this is helpful. Though I'm not sure what it means to fill in such a diagram, this must have something to do with a higher degree simplex mapping onto it, right?

Comment: @lemiller Whether the boundary of a simplex can be filled in is determined by the data of the simplicial set $S$, which is given *a priori*.